# webRequest removing a listener attached to a tabId

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

In my web extension I add multiple of the same listeners to differing tab ids based on what the user tells the extension to do.
`browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(mycallback,
        {urls: ["myurl"], tabId: varyingtabid},["blocking"]);`

But when I need to cleanup a listener for a tab, I don't know how to specify which listener, the documentation says removeListener takes only one parameter which is the callback.
`browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(mycallback);
//does this remove every listener, what does this do when there are multiple listeners?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code in api_event_listeners.cc ([link](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/renderer/bindings/api_event_listeners.cc?l=225&rcl=36125a320bf94d4f19e19f5f3176035b9095fd1c)), removeListener removes all registrations for the specified listener regardless of filters used for adding that listener.

That's because you can't add the same listener multiple times with different filters ([link](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/renderer/bindings/api_event_listeners.cc?l=161&rcl=36125a320bf94d4f19e19f5f3176035b9095fd1c)):

```
    // Note that we only consider the listener function here, and not the
    // filter. This implies that it's invalid to try and add the same
    // function for multiple filters.
    // TODO(devlin): It's always been this way, but should it be?
```

In other words, every time you invoke addListener with the *same function reference*, it's a [no-op](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/renderer/bindings/api_event_listeners.cc?l=191&rcl=36125a320bf94d4f19e19f5f3176035b9095fd1c).

---

Note, if you declare the callback inside another function, the callback reference will be different each time, because in JS `function name() {}` is equivalent to `var name = function () {}` with the added convenience of it being declared before the first statement of the encompassing function.

Comment: Is there anyway to dynamically create different function references to one function, and use that reference as the listener callback? I tried using an object that that didn't work when creating the listener.

Comment: Assuming `foo()` is a global/persistent function, you can simply use a wrapper: function() { return foo.apply(this, arguments); }